# Flask app concurrent users

Tags: python, api, flask, wsgi

i'm using a flask app to host my python engine so that it can be accessed by a web app which hosts the GUI for the flask app. using wsgi but not sure about concurrency? can any one shed some light on this?

Comment: What do you want to know about concurrency?

Comment: have  like a lot of users being able to ping my enginge so  that they can access functionality

Comment: And are they not able to at the moment? What is the problem you are trying to solve exactly?

Comment: i've passed the basic app.WSGIserver(('0.0.0.0',8080),app) and running it forever, will this do or do i need to do anything else! a( have already done monkey patching as well)

Comment: That should do. Unless your app can't handle the load. Then you may want to think of deploying it behind a load balancer to distribute load between application instances.

Comment: for about 10 -20 it should do right

Comment: It should be fine

Comment: The builtin in Flask development server can only handle one request at a time. You shouldn't use it for real use.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton any idea how do i fix this

Comment: There are other WSGI servers which are better suited for real production use cases. Use one of them.

Comment: thanks @GrahamDumpleton  for your advice

Comment: @MohitKodali What's the conclusion? How do you quantitatively check the number of concurrent requests your flask app can handle? Please post answer if you already have it.